# Inconsistent transparency, looking like render order issue

Tags: three.js, transparency

I am using r82.

I have a mesh with multiple materials. I can change their opacity just fine, but how they are rendered is what I would call "splotchy". I have been using ThreeJs for a while, and **EDIT: <s>was able to get the transparency working in a past version (r67) with the same model in a significantly more consistent way. So I was wondering if there is something that now I need to set that I didn't need to set before or if I am just overlooking something.</s> Upon revisiting my older code and testing it again, I found that the same transparency issues were present. It was simply a matter of there not being as obvious "splotches" (and not testing enough, I'm sure).** Here is a screenshot.[image]

Here are a few more pictures I took that highlight the issue a bit better. I have the outside wall in a light grey and the floors a dark grey in the model and can toggle the outside walls to be visible or not. In these pictures I have one face of the outside wall purple and a face of the floor in the room on the other side of the wall green.

[image: Outside wall purple face]

[image: Inside floor green face]

Based on the angle of the camera, it makes part of the green floor face invisible even though there is only one face between the camera and it.
[image: transparent green face partially invisible]

The materials are all double sided already and there is no sign of this until the transparency is on. I found a similar question that suggested changing the mesh.setFaceCulling (or something similar) but that seemed to be from an older version and wasn't in r82.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT:**
 I started looking into the old version of threeJS and the current version's source code to see what is done differently regarding transparency. I found transparentObjects, which is an array of the objects (I believe faces) that are going to be rendered and are in sorted based on "reversePainterSortStable". There is another list of objects (I believe for the materials objects, maybe?) called opaqueObjects that uses "painterSortStable". So to see if changing the sort order would change the outcome of how things are looking when transparent I changed it so that transparentObjects got sorted by "painterSortStable" and it did change how things showed up significantly (granted it didn't fix my problem since it just removed some problem spots and created new ones).

So the short version, it looks like it is an issue with the renderOrder of the faces.

That being said, I tried finding how the r67 version of the code handled the "renderOrder" of the faces since it wasn't something that (to my knowledge) could be set in that version and just did it automatically. But I have had no such luck tracking down how it was done as of yet.

So I see two possibilities. 1) find out how the past version correctly did transparency (at least for my purposes) and change the logic in the current version to use that. Or 2) find how to properly set the renderOrder of the faces based on the camera position in the scene. Will look into the second option first, but figured it would be good to document this for others looking to help answer or that have a similar problem.

**EDIT 2:**
So digging through the source code for threeJs and noticed something about the transparentObjects array I mentioned in the previous edit. The first, that I cannot for the life of me figure out how it gets populated since it doesn't seem like it is added to anywhere in the code. The second is that I think it is being populated with duplicates of the entire building object/mesh (see screenshot below).

[image]

The z indexes all seem to be the same. as well as the ids and the objects are all of type "mesh" (of the ones I looked through, granted, since there are a few thousand). So I was going to figure out why its adding what is being added to the array, but that is when I stumbled across the issue of not finding where in the code that the transparentObjects array actually get populated.

**EDIT 3:**

WestLangley, I tried setting the depth test for the outer wall material to false and got this. Like I said in my response comment, even if it did work it wouldn't fix the issues experienced with the camera inside the building, but wanted to follow up none the less (see snapshot below).

[image]

Comment: Set only the outer wall to be transparent and try `outerwall_material.depthWrite = false;` Make everything else opaque. You can always set mesh.renderOrder.

Comment: @WestLangley I don't think setting the outerwall_material.depthWrite will fix the issue since the problem is still present when the camera is inside of the building and looking through a wall. I will show what I mean in a bit after I post another update with something else I found. Also, setting the render order just changes if it is lowest to highest priority or highest to lowest priority, doesn't it? And that is for full objects/meshes, not faces of an object.

Comment: (1) Well, at least you will learn about all the complications in handling transparency in webgl, and how three.js addresses the issue... (2) three.js sorts objects, not faces. Faces are rendered in the order they appear in the buffer. You may be able to improve things by breaking your model into smaller pieces so all meshes don't have the same position (and hence have different distances from the camera).

Comment: Fair enough. Well now the question is how much of an effect would turning 31,000 faces into objects put on performance? Granted I am going to try this, but I figure if you or anyone knows that just would be too strenuous or a better way, I'll try that first. Thanks for the help regardless, @WestLangley

Comment: Ouch... You can remove the transparency if you can't get it to work and as a work-around use `Object3D.layers` to toggle layers on and off...

Comment: Yea, its not exactly small. And didn't know about object.layers. Have just been giving each level/layer its own material that I change to be visible or invisible. So good to know about that at least haha.